# Diagnosing Root Cause of Increasing AWS Cloudwatch Costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cost-management

Over the past few months our Cloudwatch costs have steadily risen. This seems to be caused by metric updates. RUM was enabled for a short time but has been disabled for about 2 months now. This is not a high traffic account only currently being used for development by a single person. Help troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

May
[image: May]

June
[image: June]

July
[image: July]

August Current
[image: August Current]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Metric updates operation is related to [CloudWatch Metric Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudwatch-metric-streams-send-aws-metrics-to-partners-and-to-your-apps-in-real-time/) which can be used to send CloudWatch metrics to an AWS partner e.g. New Relic, Datadog, Dynatrace, etc.

As indicated in [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) it has a cost of $0.003 per 1,000 metric updates.

To check if you have one or more metric streams enabled enter to CloudWatch -> Metrics -> Streams:

[image: CloudWatch Metric Streams on console]

And then you can delete it, stop it or re-configure it to limit the ingestion to a specific metric namespace

[image: CloudWatch Metric Streams example]

Comment: New relic was integrated a few months back. On the surface that appears to be the cause. I wonder whether the polling alternative would reduce the cost any. For now the stream has been stopped. https://newrelic.com/blog/best-practices/aws-cloudwatch-metric-streams